# Laravel: How to pass a collection to view?

Tags: laravel

The `$result` variable displays the json-string correctly. And when I try to send the `result` to the view, I get an error.

```
$accreditations = Accreditation::with(['country'])->get();
$result = AccreditationResource::collection($accreditations);
    
//return $result;
//{"data":[{"id":5,"user_id":1,"login":"Admin","country_id":"4","country":{"id":4,"name":"Austria"}}]}

return View::make('accred_table', $result->login);
//Error 500: Property [login] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Help me figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$result is an array. So, there is no login as the error said. If you return only one record from AccreditationResource, you can use

```
return view('accred_table', ['login' => $result[0]['login']]);
```

In blade, you will have $login.